# Accessing internal method from Kotlin through Java

Tags: android, kotlin

How to access an internal Kotlin method through Java class without using the wierd syntax < method_name >$< module >()?

Code example.

**Kotlin class:**

```
class MyKotlinClass {
    internal fun myInternalKotlinMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**Java class:**

```
public class MyJavaClass {
    public MyJavaClass() {
        MyKotlinClass myKotlinClass = new MyKotlinClass();
        myKotlinClass.myInternalKotlinMethod$app_debug();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `MyJavaClass` & `MyKotlinClass` part of different modules right?

Comment: They are at same module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way around this. This is how it is supposed to work.

According to the official docs on [calling Kotlin code from Java code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#visibility) (emphasis mine):

> - `internal` declarations become `public` in Java. **Members of `internal` classes go through name mangling**, to make it harder to accidentally
>     use them from Java and to allow overloading for members with the same
>     signature that don't see each other according to Kotlin rules;

Answer (score 4):

You may use `JvmName` to achieve the point:

```kotlin
class MyKotlinClass {
    @JvmName("myInternalKotlinMethod")
    internal fun myInternalKotlinMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there isn't any other alternative to call `internal` from Java Class. If you can decompile your Kotlin code to Java; you will exactly see how Kt is converted to Java. So to invoke that method must be using the same naming convention.

If you are using IntelliJ, you can use Tools → Kotlin → Show kotlin ByteCode → Decompile

Decompiled Kotlin to Java Class

MyKotlinClass.kt → MyKotlinClass.java(Decompiled)

```
public final class MyKotlinClass {
  //app_debug is your module name
  public final void myInternalKotlinMethod$app_debug() {

  }
}
```

MyJavaClass.java

```
public class MyJavaClass {
   public MyJavaClass() {
     MyKotlinClass myKotlinClass = new MyKotlinClass();
     myKotlinClass.myInternalKotlinMethod$app_debug();
  }
}
```

> I'm afraid you have to use `myInternalKotlinMethod$app_debug();` from java class.